# C# Member 'System.Char[] System.String::ToCharArray()' is declared in another module and needs to be imported in Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, obfuscation, mono.cecil

I use Mono.Cecil to encrypt my strings in my assemblies.

but in

```
myAssemblyDefinition.Write(myAssemblyPath);
```

I get an error:

> Member 'System.Char[] System.String::ToCharArray()' is declared in
>   another module and needs to be imported

I tried to import `String.ToCharArray` method with all these lines:

```
myAssemblyDefinition.MainModule.Import(stringTypeReference.Resolve());
myAssemblyDefinition.MainModule.Import(stringTypeReference.Resolve().Module.Types.Where(x => x.Name == "String").First());
MethodDefinition toCharArrayMethod = stringTypeReference.Resolve().Module.Types.Where(x => x.Name == "String").First().Methods.Where(x => x.Name == "ToCharArray").First();
myAssemblyDefinition.MainModule.Import(toCharArrayMethod);
myAssemblyDefinition.MainModule.Import(typeof(System.String));
```

but my problem still exists.
I used `ToCharArray` method for inject `decryptMethod` to my assembly.
Can anybody help to me to solve this or
is there a sample code to encrypt string for obfuscating with Mono.Cecil 0.9.5 version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your target assembly's runtime version is same with your injection code's runtime version.
Try following lines.

```
var toCharArray =
 asm.MainModule.Import(typeof(string).GetMethod("ToCharArray", new Type[] { }));
proccer.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, toCharArray);
```

Comment: Thanks.
also my problem was i used codes from Mono.Cecil 0.6 insted of Mono.Cecil 0.9
and i solved this by read this link [https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/Importing](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/Importing)